# LD_PRELOAD for setuid binary

Tags: linux, rhel, ld

I'm trying to override malloc/free functions for the program, that requires setuid/setgid permissions. I use the LD_PRELOAD variable for this purpose. According to the [ld documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so), I need to put my library into one of the standard search directories (I chose /usr/lib) and give it setuid/setgid permissions. I've done that. However, I still can't link to my .so file, getting the error:

`object 'liballoc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored`

What can be the possible reasons for that? Tested this .so file on programs that don't have setuid/setgid permissions and all works fine.
OS: RedHat 7.0

Comment: @ilkkachu linking to a man page doesn't mean you've read it all or understood every possible ramification of it.  I speak from personal experience here. "skim, skim, skim, oh fsck why didn't i notice that paragraph earlier".

Comment: Are you running it as root or as a mortal user?  If the latter, then `ld.so` will be in secure execution mode.  It would help to show the permission bits on `liballoc.so` to confirm that you've set those correctly (IIRC, you need to set the library's setgid and setuid bits to indicate that you intend it to be preloaded into set?id processes).

Comment: @cas, well, sure. As for that, just saying "read the man page" also doesn't help, since it doesn't tell what part they missed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> According to the ld documentation, I need to put my library into one of the standard search directories (I chose `/usr/lib`)

That was the mistake. You should've put it in `/usr/lib64` (assuming that your machine is a x86_64).

I've just tried the recipe from the manpage on a Centos 7 VM (which should be ~identical to RHEL 7) and it works:

As root:

```
cynt# cc -shared -fPIC -xc - <<<'char *setlocale(int c, const char *l){ errx(1, "not today"); }' -o /usr/lib64/liblo.so
cynt# chmod 4755 /usr/lib64/liblo.so
```

As a regular user with a setuid program:

```
cynt$ LD_PRELOAD=liblo.so su -
su: not today
```

---

Whether it's a good idea to use that feature is a totally different matter (IMHO, it isn't).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning how to determine which directories are suitable.  On my Debian machines, they are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` - I guess that's the same on Red Hat?

Answer (score 6):

`man ld.so`

> **Secure-execution mode**
> For  security reasons, if the dynamic linker determines that a binary should be run in secure-execution mode, the effects of some environment variables are voided or modified
> [...]
> A binary is executed in secure-execution mode if
>
> - The process's real and effective user IDs differ
>
> [...]
> **LD_PRELOAD**
> In  secure-execution  mode,  preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored.  Furthermore, shared objects are preloaded only from the standard search directories and only if they have set-user-ID mode bit enabled (which is not typical).

If a SUID binary is executed then this situation occurs: real UID and effective UID differ. But if this binary executes a different (non-SUID) binary then the EUID of the parent becomes the RUID and EUID of the child:

```
sudo sleep 1000 &

ps -o pid,ruid,euid,args --pid $! --ppid $!
  PID  RUID  EUID COMMAND
 7286  1000     0 sudo sleep 1000
 7287     0     0 sleep 1000
```

So if you want to avoid the LD_PRELOAD restrictions you can call your binary via sudo or create a wrapper SUID binary which calls the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is to prevent malicious code elevation.
A C program does *not* start running in main(). Instead, the C Runtime Library is called first, which set up its environment (including the STDIO streams), any global variables that aren't compile-time constants, and then calls into main().

A malicious actor can use LD_PRELOAD= to override the libc.o library with a custom library with a modified startup function that does (for example) - restores LD_PRELOAD, and then invokes /bin/sh. If LD_PRELOAD= wasn't ignored for a SUID process, that user could then run /bin/passwd, and they now have a root shell. From there they can now install a rootkit, etc.